# how to find the id of html element that is generated from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating html list items from a Json. The ID is equal to its ID in the JSON. So I can not specifically refer to id='thing'. Question is, how do I, in later functions, get the function to refer to the id of the object when I only know what id = i?

```
html += "<li class='list-item ui-state-default addNewContext' id=" + i + ">" + card.card_name + ' - ' + card.price + "<button> X </button>" + "</li>" ; /
```

Comment: `var liObj = $j('#'+id)`

Answer (score 1):

You already have the `i` which is the id. Do you mean you want a reference to the element with that id?

```
var myObj = jQuery("#" + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want id of your list you can do like this.

```
var x = $(".addNewContext"); // class on list 

var id = x.attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is wrong. You should wrap `id` with single quotes in your code because of `id=1` means nothing to browser but `id='1'` does.

```
html += "<li class='list-item ui-state-default addNewContext' id='" + i + "'>" + card.card_name + ' - ' + card.price + "<button> X </button>" + "</li>" ;
```

You can access this element by :

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

or in jQuery :

```
$("#" + id)
```

Comment: The code is not incorrect, it works perfectly fine the way it is right now. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real question is how you are adding your variable `html` to your DOM. Using jQuery's [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/), the id `thing` will accessible via `$('#thing')`. [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/christhorsvik/5mwswc48/).

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery you could also reference its position in the list (assuming i doesnt increment by 1)

```
$('.list-item:eq(0)').text()
```

Where `:eq(#)` is the location of the item in the list

If the function is being referenced within the generated list item you could also try navigating up the dom with jQuery's parent() functions: https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: I guess the question here would be, how do I reference its location on the list...Basically here is what happens...We import the JSON,  It generates the html list, the items are drag and drop, so their position changes.. then on export is reassigns their seq numbers and sends off the JSON to where it is going

Comment: So the `:eq()` will show you where it is now in time (so after the position changes)